# Missing maven dependencies and compilation error in eclipse project, STS 4.15.3 windows version

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I'm going through this difficulty, I'm new to using this technology. Before formatting the machine, this project was running perfectly, I backed up everything and formatted. Now that I try to import the project into the software I come across some errors.

I performed the import through `Maven->existing maven projects`, the build runs, but returns the following errors:

1. Error in `pom.xml` file.
2. Some maven dependencies are missing.
3. Build path specifies JavaSE-11 execution environment. There are no
   JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with
   this environment.
4. The compiler compliance specified is 11 but a JRE 17 is used.

Please,look at the prints:
[image: POM file]
[image: Error Log]
[image: Properties]
[image: Properties]

Since then I have been trying to resolve these issues, I have checked the versions of java, jre, jdk and the like. I managed to partially solve the jre problem but after some time I had conflicts again, but involving maven dependencies I didn't get any success.

Honestly I don't understand the reason for the errors, I kept the same computer settings before formatting, that is, I installed the versions that were before.

Comment: Hey there, please copy the content of the related files properly formatted in your question. And also include the **EXACT** error logs. [ask]

Comment: The screenshots show a pretty outdated Eclipse. Please make sure your software is up to date before asking.

Comment: Where does it say, "Error in pom.xml file."? Does the Problems View show what the error is? As @Nico asked, do you have the log output from the build that you can show, when run with `-e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to look into the preferences for the installed JDKs/JREs for your workspace. You can find those settings via `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`. There you can see which JREs are configured to be used by the IDE for your projects (in general).

Then, please also take a look at the `Execution Environment` category below that preference node. There you can define which JRE should be used for which execution environment. Your project seem to require a `JavaSE-11` environment. When you select that environment from the list, you will see which installed JRE the IDE will use to fulfill that JavaSE-11 requirement of the project.

I would also run a `Maven -> Update Project---`, since the dependences that are marked in the pom.xml file seem to be just fine, so probably a broken download of those dependencies, but also hard to say without the exact errors being mentioned.

Comment: Hi Martim Lippert, thank you very much for your help, your opinion and points raised were extremely important. I had already seen something similar here on the site, but I tried my best to have the best understanding, this way of specifying `JavaSE-11` was excellent, on `maven` I did a little similar, but I had to force the update because in the conventional way the error still persisted.